# Changing image of side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for a code which can change li image of left side navigation with click. I have 4 options and 8 images but want only one to be activated at one time.

```
<div class="aside important">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about_content"><img src="../images/about_active.png" alt=""  /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#content_advantage"><img src="../images/advantage.png" alt=""  /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#content_partner"><img src="../images/partners.png" alt=""  /></a></li>
            <li><a href="#content_history"><img src="../images/history.png" alt=""  /></a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want only one active image at a time. Please help me with a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use static images, you should use css class instead of img. Its more flexible for future changes.

example:
1) make css like

```
.nav-but { background: url(yourimg) 0 -20px no-repeat; } // with -20px because its normal bg
```

2) make second active css like

```
.nav-but:hover, .active { background: url(yourimg) 0 0px no-repeat; }  // 0px as second part of bg used for active and hover
```

3) if are you using jquery you can add class active like

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

source for working example

[make menu button](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/12/how-to-create-pure-css-rollover-to-display-single-or-multiple-elements-at-remote-area/) 
[button class](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/12/16/pressed-button-state-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achive this in two different ways?

1. You can use javascript to change the image src when an element is clicked (whether the anchor or the list item) depending on your css definitions
2. Or, you can get rid of the images and use css to style your menu by using the background css property and then use css pseudo classes to change the background image.

I personally prefer the second option because it is a much cleaner approach.

Let me know if it makes sense to you

Leo